# Refresh listview onpost execute asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, adapter, custom-lists

i know this question has been posted multiple times and i browsed almost all of them but there is not result, i am performing a deleting an item from mysql database but it is not refreshing, here is the code of the onclicklistener and the button:

onClick listener:

```
 holder.void_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
    adapter = new CustomListViewVoidAdapter(context,R.layout.mytemp, items);
    item_selected= items.get(position);
        new DeleteOrder().execute();
               }});
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
```

OnPostExecute from AsyncTask:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String unused){
            adapter.remove(item_selected);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

the adapter is instatiated globally, can you please check where the problem might be?
it is not returning any error, just deleting the item and not refreshing.

Regards

Ralph

Answer (score 1):

Throwing it out there, but, have you tried adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();? That forces an update.

Also, put the code in the asynctask!

Like such:

```
protected void onPostExecute() {

   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();


}
```

Comment: yea it is in the Asynctask, i just copied the onpostexecute part, anw ill try the notifydatasetinvalidated and get back to u.. thank you

Comment: Wait. you've declared the listview in the OnCreate or somewhere else before, right? Otherwise how should the UI know that you're refering to a Listview? (Just trying to clarify, looking at the comments below).

Comment: there is no onCreate .. it is an adapter... i declared the listview at the beginning of the code

Answer (score 0):

You better set the adapter again to the list view in `onPostExecute` with the new values. And you don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged`in this case. Also don't re-intialize the adapter in `onClick`, this is not neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in postExecute.

```
if(adapter != null) { 
    adapter = new CustomListViewVoidAdapter(context,R.layout.mytemp, items);
    YourListviewObject.setAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

Comment: it returns an error at the line: lv.setAdapter(adapter)
should the code under postexecute be like this?:


      adapter = new    CustomListViewVoidAdapter(context,R.layout.mytemp, items);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       adapter.remove(item_selected);
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: adapter.remove(item_selected); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); these two lines are not required. What is the error ?

Comment: okay... stopped giving me errors... but not refreshing since i deleted the remove(item_selected) and notifyydatasetchanged as u said.. how do i get it to refresh?

Comment: add these line once adapter.remove(item_selected); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();